# Did anyone ever confirm the canonical Monty Hall problem results by analyzing actual TV shows?

Tags: game-show

One of the most vexing paradoxes in probability theory is the [Monty Hall problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem), which is from a 1960s TV show called *"Let's Make a Deal"*, hosted by Monty Hall.  The standard setup is that the player is shown 3 doors.  Only one has a valuable prize.

After the player picks a door, Monty Hall takes the two unpicked doors (2/3 chance of it being there) and opens up one of them, never the one with the prize. Now there are only 2 doors.  He then offers the player a chance to switch.

The puzzle has been very confusing.  When Marilyn vos Savant proposed a solution, as many as 1000 people with doctorates challenged her, some challenging her results, others her presumptions about specific game host behaviour.  Yet she stuck to her guns, and made her point to many.   However, why is there so much debate about theory and rule meanings, when a *canonical* source exists to answer both?

The Monty Hall problem is, after all, modeled on a real thing with a statistically significant number of plays.

My question is **not** about the mathematical theory, and the Internet is already heavy with that debate; *please add none here*.  This quesion is: has anyone ever gone back and looked at actual tapes, films or business records of the *Let's Make a Deal* show, and tallied how the contestants actually did?

Comment: Part of the problem with this question is that many believe (and I'm not taking sides here, just pointing it out), that the problem as stated does not actually follow how the show actually works. *If that is true*, then it doesn't make sense to go back and check how they did because the show doesn't work that way.

Comment: This doesn't look like "Trivia questions that do not add to the understanding or appreciation of a movie/TV-show" Its an analysis question

Comment: Note that there is no controversy. There is a right answer, which can be proven easily enough, and many wrong answers, so I don’t understand what this exercise is meant to accomplish.

Comment: @user1118321 You seem to be about to write an insightful answer to the question.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson SE doesn't have enough server space to contain all that could be written about the *theory* of the Monty Hall problem. But I'd rather they not here: theories need data to back them up, and in this case the data is historical and literally canon.  I aim to confine the discussion only to that: actual player results in the real game.

Comment: I wasn't insinuating a discussion on the mathematical validity of the problem itself, but...if the problem doesn't actually follow how the show works (at least as posited in that comment), that very much *is* some kind of answer to this question, if reasoned properly, of course.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson my concern is that there is oh, so much theory and oh, so little empirical data... I fear if theorycrafting gets its nose in the tent...  I would rather see the data first, then what exact problem this data is applicable to. By my view, the show is canonical,it *confers* the problem, and discussion of the differences should follow the data, not lead it.

Comment: I contend this is unanswerable, as no one has yet to do so and it's not likely anyone will.  However, if you saw Mythbusters Season 16, episode 7 (aka Episode 177), you'd know that Adam and Jamie tried this 50 times with Adam always switching his pick and Jamie never switching his pick.  Adam won more times, which would indicate that the correct solution would be to switch.  https://mythresults.com/wheel-of-mythfortune

Comment: @JohnnyBones - FYI -  Just ran an Excel random number generator, with the original choice always being "Door Two", one staying put, one switching, 5000 trials. Staying put won 33.1%, switching, 66.9%. Basically, there is only a 1/3 chance that the original guess is correct. There is only one alternative to the original guess, so that is going to be right 2/3 of the time. It's my own "original research," so it does not qualify as data for an answer, but it's as valid as looking at the scenario from shows.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson On reconsideration I accepted your edit, but tuned it to discuss less the math and more the history.  (ironically I was a math major and was awful at history).

Comment: Wasn't my edit anyway. ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson oh, you're right, duh, I knew that... well, thank you, to whoever was there behind door #3...

Comment: @JamesMcLeod Given particular assumptions, it can be proven that a particular result is correct. But the question of what to assume is not subject to mathematical proof.

Comment: @Acccumulation, the “canonical Monty Hall problem” (as the question title describes it) is well-defined, including assumptions, so I am unsure of the context of your statement.

Answer (score 19):

As @user1118321 has pointed out no one has done this because the game is not played the way it is described in the Monty Hall Problem.

In 1991 former *Let's Make a Deal* host Monty Hall created a simulation of the show for NY Times reporter John Tierney and found the flaw in trying to use the mathematical problem to play the actual game. From the NY Times article [Behind Monty Hall's Doors: Puzzle, Debate and Answer?](https://www.nytimes.com/1991/07/21/us/behind-monty-hall-s-doors-puzzle-debate-and-answer.html)

> After the 20 trials at the dining room table, the problem also captured Mr. Hall's imagination. He picked up a copy of Ms. vos Savant's original column, read it carefully, saw a loophole and then suggested more trials.
>
> On the first, the contestant picked Door 1.
>
> "That's too bad," Mr. Hall said, opening Door 1. "You've won a goat."
>
> "But you didn't open another door yet or give me a chance to switch."
>
> "Where does it say I have to let you switch every time? I'm the master of the show. Here, try it again."
>
> On the second trial, the contestant again picked Door 1. Mr. Hall opened Door 3, revealing a goat. The contestant was about to switch to Door 2 when Mr. Hall pulled out a roll of bills.

Monty then offered the contestant increasing amounts of money, stopping at $5,000 to **not** switch doors. The contestant refused the money and switched doors.

> "You just ended up with a goat," he said, opening the door. The Problem With the Problem.
>
> Mr. Hall continued: "Now do you see what happened there? The higher I got, the more you thought the car was behind Door 2. I wanted to con you into switching there, because I knew the car was behind 1. That's the kind of thing I can do when I'm in control of the game. You may think you have probability going for you when you follow the answer in her column, but there's the psychological factor to consider."
>
> He proceeded to prove his case by winning the next eight rounds. Whenever the contestant began with the wrong door, Mr. Hall promptly opened it and awarded the goat; whenever the contestant started out with the right door, Mr. Hall allowed him to switch doors and get another goat. The only way to win a car would have been to disregard Ms. vos Savant's advice and stick with the original door.

And here is why you can't verify the Monty Hall Problem by looking at the game show:

> Was Mr. Hall cheating? **Not according to the rules of the show, because he did have the option of not offering the switch, and he usually did not offer it.**

So basically it's as @user 1118321 said, the game on the show is not played according to the rules of the mathematical problem.

Comment: That, too, would be provable; the frequency with which Monty simply awards the goat would approach 2/3.

Comment: @Harper True, but it wouldn't verify the Monty Hall problem which states that the host MUST offer the option to switch.

Comment: It would be exposed as an academic fiction, and force a correct statement of the problem.  No wonder so many people struggle with the problem, since circa 1990 most would have actually seen the show regularly.

Comment: @Harper Even with a correct statement of the problem people still don't understand the solution or why switching is the right decision.  It's a matter of people believing their intuition instead of math.

Comment: According to wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem , Marilyn vos Savant's original wording was: <<Suppose you're on a game show, and you're given the choice of three doors: Behind one door is a car; behind the others, goats. You pick a door, say No. 1, and the host, who knows what's behind the doors, opens another door, say No. 3, which has a goat. He then says to you, "Do you want to pick door No. 2?" Is it to your advantage to switch your choice?>> There's nothing in there that says the host has to switch.

Comment: @Acccumulation That wasn't vos Savant's wording. That was Craig Whitaker's wording. If you check under the Standard Assumptions paragraph vos Savant stated the problem again in 1991 and included the rule about the host having to offer the switch.

Comment: @Legion600 So, Whitaker asked the question without including the assumptions, and vos Savant originally did not include them either. So your claim that " the Monty Hall problem [...] states that the host MUST offer the option to switch." **A** Monty Hall problem says that the host must offer the option, but it is not correct to say that **the** Monty Hall problem says so. There is no single "the" Monty Hall problem. There are different versions, and the version that vos Savant originally presented did not have this requirement.

Comment: @Acccumulation Steve Selvin, who originated the Monty Hall problem set the original switching rules. vos Savant's 1991 response is quoted on the wikipedia page under Other Host Behaviors wherein she says  that only by following those rules do you end up with the 2/3 probability of winning by switching. She also said "Anything else is a different question." Several of these are noted under different names on the page. So yes there is a single "The" Monty Hall Problem and those with different stipulations are called something else.